# VS Code Debugger not getting started

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

[image][image]

I tried to add configuration in the launch.json file. What else I should do to start the debugger. I want to add a debugger to the index.js file. The screenshot for my folder structure has been attached.Please help me.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/pg_mapper/routes/index.js",
            "request": "launch",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The log shows debugger attached! Whats the issue ?

Comment: It got solved.Thank you for your reply